# Is it POSSIBLE for a wireless device to use the cellular frequencies without approval from the FCC

Tags: wireless, fcc, cellular

My question is purely hypothetical and does NOT apply to any real life scenarios. Is it possible for a wireless device to use the cellular quad band successfully without FCC approval or knowledge.

Comment: If "possible" is to be taken at face value the answer is obviously yes since anything can be built without approval. Not to mention "use" is somewhat vague as well since broadband generators can be built to hit anything, like jammers. I feel you have more context in mind but you aren't saying it.

Comment: No, it isn't. An intentional radiator cannot be used without approvals. And using such a device in someone elses radio band will be a sure way to get into trouble, because cellular devices can detect interference. I know of at least one instance where a sign company had one of their products turn into an unintentional radiator in a cellular band, the cell company came knocking on their door.

Comment: Is it possible to do something illegal?  I strayed into the cellular band once and got a visit from the local equiv of the FCC. They were armed with a Yagi and spectrum analyser. Seems the local cell towers were detecting interference and the operators reported it. In terms of using equipment that is qualified to work with the cellular system but doesn’t have FCC approval, then the FCC will only take action if they know about it. They’ll only know if it has been reported. Otherwise you’re running under the radar.

Comment: Another reason "use" is vague is because just a receiver that is otherwise invisible is also technically using the band.

Comment: @DKNguyen is right about your writing: "use ... successfully" doesn't say much at all. You need to say a lot more. Just to add to what else's been said: It's also the case that cell phone technology uses encryption methods over RF that are simply illegal for "most of us." You have to pay a huge license fee and be a very large company to get such permits. (It also used to be that radio HAM operators could use any form of spread spectrum they could devise. They developed the ideas into practice, too. Then had it taken away from them, permanently, except for a pair of remaining "toy" concepts.)

Comment: Possible? Certainly. Devices don't work using permits, they work using batteries. 
Is it a great idea? I don't think so, but it's not as horrible one might first think.
Listening to RF communications is afaik 100% legal in any case. You could try to listen to cellular trafic - not that you'd get much out of it, as it's encrypted.
Transmitting is harder - if you want to make it work.
In any case, I doubt that every clone GSM board you can get off ebay from china has an FCC permit - and they still work (usually).
Also, technicly everybody living outside the US uses stuff w/o FCC permits...

Comment: The FCC do have the authority in the USA and use it but mainly on the big fish https://www.everycrsreport.com/reports/RL32589.html  Each country has an authority.